# Need to resolve Ubuntu 16.04 booting problem

Tags: boot

I have recently updated my workstation from Ubuntu 14 to 16.04. After this screen shows ***"Input Signal Out of Range, Change setting ti 1280x1028-60Hz"*** . To solve this I modified this line in GRUB `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1028`.

While restarting I have mistakenly entered into booting menu by pressing F12 which looks like this

```
0 bootable devices found.
Press F1 key to retry boot.
Press F2 key for setup utility.
Press F5 key to run onboard diagnostics
```

Now I cannot come out this boot menu option, I have restarted the system many times still it shows boot menu.

Comment: What if you press F1?

Comment: display just blinks and shows the same

Comment: Try changing boot priority.

Comment: how to  change boot priority?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. It varies from CPU to CPU. You can check on vendors site/forum.